# How to fsync or fdatasync in PHP?

Tags: php, filesystems

PHP lacks any specific function to fsync on a file AFAIK. I do however feel the urge to fsync a logfile I am appending to from PHP.

Is there any native PHP function known to cause an fsync? Or any workaround?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid it's not possible. The only reference to `fsync` in the sources is in the implementation of the `flush` operation for regular filesystem streams and it's just to explicitly say they're not fsyncing, only calling `fflush`.

If you really need this, you have to do it in a PHP extension.

Comment: I'm starting to think of an fsync-deamon that listens on a unix-socket and performs arbitary sync-actions. Might not be a performant, but certainly easier to maintain than an extension.

Comment: @korkman An extension for this would be trivial to make. You could also just patch the default flush operation so that it called fsync, though that could have a performance hit in other places where your scripts would call flush and an fsync was not necessary.

Comment: PHP 8.1 will include `fsync` and `fdatasync` functions.

Answer (score 2):

As of PHP 8.1 these methods are now available with the expected names.

- [fsync()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsync.php)
- [fdatasync()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fdatasync.php)

Comment: Note that `put_file_contents()` and similar still cannot be asked to sync the file before it has been closed already. If you want to sync the data to the storage, you have to `fopen()` the file, `fwrite()` to it, call `fsync()` or `fdatasync()` according to your needs and then `fclose()` it. And check the return values of all those functions before continuing and make sure to use operator `===` to make difference between zero and `false`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with a regular file, closing it with [fclose](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php) will most likely commit your changes to disk. To assure that log messages hit the disk, just open and close the file for each write to your log.

Writes to the [system log](http://php.net/manual/en/function.syslog.php) should take place immediately and are handled by the OS.

Comment: I'm not familiar at all on how the kernel manages its buffers, but I doubt this is true. If you have references, please provide them.

Comment: @Artefacto: you are correct. I just looked through the php codebase and there are no explicit calls to fsync dealing with file operations. @korkman, PHP extensions would be the way to go.

Comment: Closing a file is not necessarily enough.  Ref.: http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/doc/ubifs.html#L_writeback

Comment: Closing is definitely not enough. A simple test on Linux showed that doing `fopen()`, `fwrite()`, `fflush()`, `fclose()` and then deliberately crashing the system causes the file to not even exist after a reboot.